# How do I eliminate the "88 levels: ..." from column variable?

Tags: r, statistics

Code output (I want underlined line to be removed):
[image: Code output]

First 20 rows of matrix:
[image: Matrix; first 20 rows]

How do I eliminate the "88 levels: ..." from the 'indexdata' variable? I only want to print the date. I'm referring to a matrix with column 1 being dates, and the rest of the columns containing information about events occurring on those dates. I need to be able to print the date with the rest of the output info when searching for when specific events occurred.

```
data = read.table("/Users/.../Data.csv", sep=",", header = T) 
data

dataresults = 1
numRowData = nrow(data)
numRowData
for (i in 1:numRowData) {
  indexdata = which(data[i , ] == "S_2")
  if (length(indexdata) > 0) {
    if (indexdata[1] == 2) {
      date = data[i , 1]
      print(date[1])
      print(indexdata)
      print("True")
      dataresults = c(dataresults, "true")
    } else {
      print(indexdata)
      print("False")
      dataresults = c(dataresults, "false")
    } 
  } else {
    dataresults = c(dataresults, "empty")
  }
}
```

Comment: See [`droplevels`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/droplevels.html).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your date column is being treated as a [factor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/factor). To avoid this, set the `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` in your call to `read.table()`.

```
data = read.table("/Users/.../Data.csv", sep=",", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```